# How can i compare data output from robot framework by using python

Tags: python, robotframework

here's my robot code

```
Database-Keywords-Test

connect to database using custom params  cx_Oracle    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}

${queryResults}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_A order by SECURITY_ID
Log  ${queryResults}

${queryResults1}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_B order by SECURITY_ID
Log  ${queryResults1}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the code in any known language.

Comment: Can you share what kind of attributes does a `queryResults` object have?

Comment: @DYZ: it's a robotframework test script.

Answer (score 1):

The Robot Framework is written in Python, which makes for a number of good entry points.

You have to make a design decision (or determine the design decision already made by your team) around which to use.

**Robot native solution**

If the results from the two tables in your system are meant to be identical, you might be able to just use a built-in Robot framework keyword directly and not call out to Python at all.

```
*** Settings ***
 Documentation    Exercise database keywords (Robot-only).
 Library          Collections
 Library          # <Database library implied above>

*** Test Cases ***
User Settings Test
    [Documentation]    User details db comparison (Database-Keywords-Test)
   ${queryResultsA}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_A order by SECURITY_ID
   ${queryResultsB}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_B order by SECURITY_ID
    Lists Should Be Equal  ${queryResultsA}  ${queryResultsB}
```

**Robot invoking Python solution**

If you want Robot to drive Python, ie you invoke robot as the main entry point, you can import Python modules using the Library keyword.

Robot test case:

```
*** Settings ***
 Documentation    Exercise database keywords (call out to Python).
 Library          userManagement
 Library          # <Database library implied above>

*** Test Cases ***
User Settings Test
    [Documentation]    User details db comparison (Database-Keywords-Test)
   ${queryResultsA}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_A order by SECURITY_ID
   ${queryResultsB}=   Query  Select * from QA_USER.SealTest_Security_B order by SECURITY_ID
    ${diff} = Compare Users  ${userResultsA}  ${userResultsB}
    Should Be Empty  ${diff}
```

Python library userManagement.py:

```
class UserManagement:

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'

    def compareUsers(self,userResultsA,userResultsB):
        # diff implementation depends on the structure of user results
        # which are not shared in the question, but will be related to the 
        # database library you are using, perhaps a list of 
        # rows or dictionaries
        ...
        return diff
```

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module

**Python invoking Robot solution**

If you want python to drive Robot, you can access the API from Python
https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The above are some directly related stubs that hopefully let you see the mapping and get off the ground. Using that starting point, I suggest working through the documentation links carefully for next steps.

Comment: if you can please help me more with that, please.
I still confuse.

Comment: I already did it but one last thing.
what is '${diff} = Compare Users' i can't find 'Compare Users' on IDE

Comment: Compare Users is the invocation (in keyword style) of the compareUsers() function defined in the new Python library, userManagement.py.